# Where and how do I find the *desktop*.iso file needed to install Universal USB Installer? I need it to install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Or maybe I don't have that iso file. How do I have it? Where can I get it?

Comment: Go through this link for details http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to this webpage: http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/
2. Choose the right architecture (x86 or amd64) for your machine from the **Desktop CD** section
3. Download this file
4. Use [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to write it to a USB

See this link for more detailed instructions: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)